# Remove class on click and deselect input with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list item with a radio button input in each, on click of the list item the input is checked. However, if clicked again I want to remove the class and deselect the option. I can't seem to get anything to work however.

```
function setupToptions() {
    if ($('ul.top-options input').length) {
        $('ul.top-options li').each(function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $('ul.top-options li input:checked').each(function(){ 
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        });                
    };
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BKgdc/4/

What is wrong?

Comment: Well, where's your click handler?

Comment: As @Jack said; no `click` handler here. And where do you 'deselect' your radio buttons in the above example? I believe you should use `selected` and remove attribute `selected` when working with radio buttons. You're now using `checked` which only applies on checkboxes

Comment: @RobinvanBaalen - not true, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZK4th/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $('ul.top-options li input[type=radio]').click(function() {
     if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('active')){
         $('ul.top-options li').removeClass('active');
         $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
     }else
         $(this).removeAttr('checked').closest('li').removeClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BKgdc/8/

Comment: `$('ul.top-options li').removeClass('active');` is effectively the same as `$('ul.top-options li').each(function(){ $(this).removeClass('active'); });` but should be faster

Comment: also, those should really be `removeProp` not `removeAttr` - it is changed in 1.9+ and "might" not work in all cases as documented here: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-

Comment: I prefer use removeAttr, and removeProp is not recommended for this case, read official documentation note "Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead."

Comment: SO, it almost seems as if you should be setting `.prop('checked',false)` perhaps rather than removing? interesting to me at least :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an event handler :

```
$('ul.top-options input').change(function(){
    if ($('ul.top-options input').length) {
        $('ul.top-options li').each(function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $('ul.top-options li input:checked').each(function(){ 
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        }); 
     }
});
```

but your code can be simplified as

```
$('ul.top-options input').change(function(){
     $('ul.top-options li').removeClass('active');
     $('ul.top-options li input:checked').parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

See [**demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnRKJ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $li = $('ul.top-options li');
    $li.click(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $li.removeClass('active')
        .filter(this).addClass('active').find('input').prop('checked', true);
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            $(this).find('input').prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
    $li.filter(':has(:checked)').click();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would be to use checkboxes instead of radio buttons. No need for any javascript when using checkboxes.

If you want to deselect a radio button you should remove it's `selected` attribute. `:checked` only applies on checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely need to do this:

```
$li = $('ul.top-options li');
$li.click(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    $li.not(self).removeClass('active');
    (self.hasClass('active') ? (self.removeClass('active').find('input').prop('checked', false)) : (self.addClass('active').find('input').prop('checked', true)));
});
$li.filter(':has(:checked)').click();
```

alternate conditional form:

```
$li = $('ul.top-options li');
$li.click(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    $li.not(self).removeClass('active');
    if (self.hasClass('active')) {
        self.removeClass('active').find('input').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        self.addClass('active').find('input').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
$li.filter(':has(:checked)').click();
```

a fiddle to show in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZK4th/