# How to deselect a div after adding a class

Tags: jquery, toggle, deselect

Pls see:

https://jsfiddle.net/villete/0yf0nucj/

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
    $('.block').click(function() {
        $(".block.blockActive").removeClass("blockActive");
        $(this).addClass('blockActive');
    });
});
```

How do I **deselect** the blue div so that none of the divs are selected anymore? I think I need a toggle for this but I dont know how to implement this.

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, 
I think I got the solution.

```
    if (!$(this).hasClass('blockActive')) {
        $('.block').removeClass('blockActive');
        $(this).addClass('blockActive');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('blockActive');
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0yf0nucj/8/

Found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15229687/1364685)

Comment: Unfortunately no... I need it to work exactly as my example but then with the possibility to "deselect". so I want it to be possible to select just one div at the time. but thank you for your reply!

Comment: @villete upadated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think `toggleClass("blockActive")` is what you are searching for.